# Laravel 5.4 - Passing Data from Controller to Artisan Handle

Tags: laravel

To get things started, I made a custom Artisan Command called `MySqlRestore.`

It simply restores the database using the dumped `sql` file.

Here's my `MySqlRestore` code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class MySqlRestore extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'db:restore';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Restores database using info from .env';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $sqlfile = //data from controller;

        $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $host = env('DB_HOST');
        $username = env('DB_USERNAME');
        $password = env('DB_PASSWORD');
        $database = env('DB_DATABASE');

        $mysqlpath = 'C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql';
        $path = 'C:\salesandinventory\Backups\\';

        $command = sprintf($mysqlpath . ' --user=' . $username . ' --password=' . $password . ' --host=' . $host . ' ' . $database . ' < ' . $path . $sqlfile);

        exec($command);
    }
}
```

Now on this line `$sqlfile = //data from controller;`, I need the data from my controller.

Here's how my controller looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Database;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Artisan;

class DatabaseController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('database.index');
    }
    public function restoreDatabase(Request $request)
    {
        $sqlfile = $request->sqlfile; // the data I need.

        Artisan::call('db:restore');
        return view('database.index');
    }
}
```

Now I don't have any idea how to pass `$sqlfile = $request->sqlfile;` this data from my controller into my Artisan `handle` function.

Comment: Have you tried passing through the `constructor` ?

Comment: Is it applicable if `$sqlfile = $request->sqlfile` came from my Blade's `<input>?` Also, I haven't used this `constructor`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Data's are passed through the protected $signature using curly braces {dataName}

e.g

```
protected $signature = 'db:restore {dataName}'
```

and it is called using

```
$this->argument('dataName');
```

In your controller

```
Artisan::call('db:restore',['test'=> $test]);
```

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class MySqlRestore extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'db:restore {test}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Restores database using info from .env';

    public $sqlFile;
    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $sqlfile = $this->argument('test');

        $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $host = env('DB_HOST');
        $username = env('DB_USERNAME');
        $password = env('DB_PASSWORD');
        $database = env('DB_DATABASE');

        $mysqlpath = 'C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql';
        $path = 'C:\salesandinventory\Backups\\';

        $command = sprintf($mysqlpath . ' --user=' . $username . ' --password=' . $password . ' --host=' . $host . ' ' . $database . ' < ' . $path . $sqlfile);

        exec($command);
    }
}

Call it like this

Artisan::call('db:restore',['test'=> $test]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class MySqlRestore extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'db:restore';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Restores database using info from .env';

    public $sqlFile;
    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($sqlFile)
    {
        $this->sqlFile = $sqlFile;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $sqlfile = $this->sqlFile;

        $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $host = env('DB_HOST');
        $username = env('DB_USERNAME');
        $password = env('DB_PASSWORD');
        $database = env('DB_DATABASE');

        $mysqlpath = 'C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql';
        $path = 'C:\salesandinventory\Backups\\';

        $command = sprintf($mysqlpath . ' --user=' . $username . ' --password=' . $password . ' --host=' . $host . ' ' . $database . ' < ' . $path . $sqlfile);

        exec($command);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Database;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Artisan;

class DatabaseController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('database.index');
    }
    public function restoreDatabase(Request $request)
    {
        $sqlfile = $request->sqlfile; // the data I need.

        Artisan::call('db:restore',['sqlFile'=>$sqlFile]);
        return view('database.index');
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives me this error. `Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::call() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\Users\Zack\Google Drive\salesandinventory\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 221`

Comment: Now it's returning an error about Unresolvable Dependency:

`Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $data ]] in class App\Console\Commands\MySqlRestore`

Comment: Oh sorry, it's `$sqlfile` not `$data`.

Comment: Laravel is not able to resolve the string parameter passed through the constructor

Comment: if it helps, I'm using <input  type=file> but it still returns the value of it.

Comment: Lets chat about this https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/154759/chat-between-norris-and-jan-ariel-san-jose?tab=general

Answer (score 1):

Your controller should *not* be executing Artisan commands, especially potentially long-running ones like executing a database back-up.

Instead, consider dispatching a queued job that performs the restore. You can then return control to the user and they can get on with things they need to do, instead of keeping a web page open that could possibly timeout and leave the database in a corrupt state.

```php
class DatabaseRestoreController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        dispatch(new RestoreDatabaseJob($request->input('filename')));

        return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('Restoring database.');
    }
}
```

And the job class itself:

```php
class RestoreDatabaseJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue;

    public $filename;

    public function __construct($filename)
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        Artisan::call('db:restore', [
            'filename' => $this->filename,
        ]);

        // You can notify user restore completed
        // Send email, SMS via notification etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is passing the `filename` variable to the `command` class

Comment: Artisan::command('db:restore', [
            'filename' => $this->filename,
        ]);

Comment: `command()` was a typo as I wrote it off the cuff; the method name is actually `call()`. But you pass arguments to an Artisan command as an array as per my example.

Comment: Yes .. but its not resolved. The $filename is actually an uploaded file instance

Comment: You won’t be able to pass an uploaded file to a queued job, as they can’t be serialized. Instead, you’ll need to actually upload the file somewhere, and then pass the name of that file to the job and in turn Artisan command.

Comment: I think you should add that to the answer to avoid confusion :)